# Feed Screen titles don't work

Tags: bug, ios-app

The buttons on the feed screen which shows hot question does not seem to work for me. Every time I click on a question it just darkens but does not take me to the question at all.

[image: This part does not work]

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPad Air (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Comment: Already reported, will be fixed in 1.6.1

Comment: Ah, alright thanks :)